# Can a user with sudo privileges delete themselves?

Tags: linux, sudo

I have a scenario where sshing into Linux box using public/private keys is forbidden. I can sudo as root into the box. I need to do run some script on the box. I cannot use my username and password to log in as this will expose my password to the world. So I have created a new user 'admin' with sudo privileges and log into the box as admin. After configurations are done, I need to delete the admin. Since I have logged in as admin, I cannot delete the admin. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How would logging in with a password expose it to the world?

Comment: Much of his makes little sense. If you can give some more detail on why each restriction/constraint exists, as well as what you have tried and/or researched already, we might be better able to answer or suggest alternatives. (In truth, the sysadmin side of me is screaming "This sounds like a 'how do I hack a system and remove all trace of my ever logging in to it?' type question.")

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot use my username and password to log in as this will expose my password to the world.

I can't see how this follows. SSH authentication happens over an encrypted connection, so you're only exposing your password to the remote host (and your own computer). That could of course be a problem if you use the same password in other systems (which you shouldn't do), or accidentally type the password to the wrong system.

In any case, if you can't use passwords, and you can't use key-based authentication, I wonder how you get as far as `sudo` anyway.

> Since I have logged in as admin, I cannot delete the admin.

I wouldn't be so sure about that. Some "user-friendly" utilities might try to tell you not to, but nothing stops you from editing the user database (with `vipw` or whatever) or removing files as long as you have a superuser-level shell running. Of course if your connection breaks while you're in the middle of doing that, you may have issues.

Also at least [Debian's `userdel` also has the `--force` option](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/passwd/userdel.8.en.html) to remove the user even if they're still logged in.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to just disable the user (null the password and remove sudo rights). You can do this as that user through sudo. Once logged out, you will no longer able to log in.

Another is to use a cron job that runs as root, verifies the presence of `/home/admin` and, in that case, removes the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could time it for later using `at`. As `root`:

```
at 18:00 <<HERE
/usr/sbin/deluser --remove-home admin
HERE
```

Check the queue with `atq`, remove a job with `atrm <ID>`.

Assumes `at` is installed and the daemon is running (e.g. as `atd.service` via systemd)